# nginx 301 redirect query string

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect this ugly url,

```
/index.php/component/qs/?com=qs&id=1234
```

to,

```
/product/?id=1234
```

So I thought to do something like this,

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen 443 [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

server_name www.example.com;

root /home/example/public_html/;

index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
if($query_string ~ "id=(\d+)") {
rewrite ^.*$ /products/?id=$1 permanent;
}}

location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
}
```

when I run `nginx -t` I get the following error,

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($query_string"
```

I had this working under Apache but am new to Nginx, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the complete nginx configuration?

Comment: Additional directives under location / are `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`.  Its set to use SSL, fastcgi, php-fpm. The entire config is 130 lines long (mostly irrelevant stuff) so can you be more specific?

Comment: The entire configuration is best, since it is easy declare relevant stuff as irrelevant.

Comment: I added as many details as possible, the other rules were all redirects and there are some comments.

Answer (score 1):

nginx stores URL query parameters in `$arg_name` parameters.

Therefore, you can use `$arg_id` in your `if` statement. Furthermore, you should should use another location before your `location /` directive:

```
location /index.php/component/qs {
    if ($arg_id) {
        rewrite ^ /products/?id=$arg_id permanent;
    }
}
```

If `$arg_id` is an empty string, the `if` statement is not executed. In `rewrite`, `^` is the shortest form of telling it to rewrite any URL. Since the URL and `id` argument are matched earlier, there is no need to do any matching in `rewrite` statement.

Comment: Hmm, now starting to wonder if my version of nginx doesn't include these directives, I am getting error `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($arg_id)"`.. I am running ubuntu 16.04, apt install nginx

Comment: Sorry to trouble you further, but do you know of another way to redirect without using the conditional if... would something like `rewrite ^/index.php/component/qs/.*id=(\d+)$ /products/index.php?id=$1 permanent;` work?

Comment: Well, I got it working, I used `location /index.php/component/qs { rewrite ^ /products/?id=$arg_id permanent; }`.  So I removed the if part and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: If passing the an empty parameter to `id` is OK with your CMS, then it can be like that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing space after the `if` directive name. It should be:

```
if ($query_string ~ "id=(\d+)")
```

not

```
if($query_string ~ "id=(\d+)")
```